# Python Multiprocessing: Adding to Queue Within Child Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to implement a file crawler that stores data to a Mongo. I would like to use `multiprocessing` as a way to 'hand off' blocking tasks such as unzipping files, file crawling and uploading to Mongo. There are certain tasks that are reliant on other tasks (i.e., a file needs to be unzipped before files can be crawled), so I would like the ability to complete the necessary task and add new ones to the same task queue.

Below is what I currently have:

```
import multiprocessing


class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, task_queue: multiprocessing.Queue):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.task_queue = task_queue

    def run(self):
        for (function, *args) in iter(self.task_queue.get, None):
            print(f'Running: {function.__name__}({*args,})')

            # Run the provided function with its parameters in child process
            function(*args)

            self.task_queue.task_done()


def foo(task_queue: multiprocessing.Queue) -> None:
    print('foo')
    # Add new task to queue from this child process
    task_queue.put((bar, 1))


def bar(x: int) -> None:
    print(f'bar: {x}')


def main():
    # Start workers on separate processes
    workers = []
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    task_queue = manager.Queue()
    for i in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        worker = Worker(task_queue)
        workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()

    # Run foo on child process using the queue as parameter
    task_queue.put((foo, task_queue))

    for _ in workers:
        task_queue.put(None)

    # Block until workers complete and join main process
    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()

    print('Program completed.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Expected Behaviour:

```
Running: foo((<AutoProxy[Queue] object, typeid 'Queue' at 0x1b963548908>,))
foo
Running: bar((1,))
bar: 1
Program completed.
```

Actual Behaviour:

```
Running: foo((<AutoProxy[Queue] object, typeid 'Queue' at 0x1b963548908>,))
foo
Program completed.
```

I am quite new to multiprocessing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're putting a `None` into the queue for each of the workers (causing them to end), before any of the workers have had a chance to add their own elements to the queue.  In fact, you have an interesting problem.   You can't stop any worker until every worker is in a wait state.  As long as one worker is still working, there's a chance it'll add a lot more work to the queue.  I'm not sure of the solution.

Comment: Rather unimportant but the code says `print('Program completed.')` while your output is `Program ended.`

Comment: @lenin Whoops, wanted to introduce better logging. Fixed.

Comment: @FrankYellin, ah yes, makes total sense. I've looked further into waiting until the queue is empty and believe I have found a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @FrankYellin noted, this is due to the fact that `None` is being put into `task_queue` before `bar` can be added.

Assuming that the queue will either be non-empty or waiting for a task to complete
during the program (which is true in my case), the `join` method on the queue can be used. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join):

> Blocks until all items in the queue have been gotten and processed.
>
> The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an item is added to the
> queue. The count goes down whenever a consumer thread calls
> task_done() to indicate that the item was retrieved and all work on it
> is complete. When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, join()
> unblocks.

Below is the updated code:

```
import multiprocessing


class Worker(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, task_queue: multiprocessing.Queue):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.task_queue = task_queue

    def run(self):
        for (function, *args) in iter(self.task_queue.get, None):
            print(f'Running: {function.__name__}({*args,})')

            # Run the provided function with its parameters in child process
            function(*args)

            self.task_queue.task_done() # <-- Notify queue that task is complete


def foo(task_queue: multiprocessing.Queue) -> None:
    print('foo')
    # Add new task to queue from this child process
    task_queue.put((bar, 1))


def bar(x: int) -> None:
    print(f'bar: {x}')


def main():
    # Start workers on separate processes
    workers = []
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    task_queue = manager.Queue()
    for i in range(multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
        worker = Worker(task_queue)
        workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()

    # Run foo on child process using the queue as parameter
    task_queue.put((foo, task_queue))

    # Block until all items in queue are popped and completed
    task_queue.join() # <---

    for _ in workers:
        task_queue.put(None)

    # Block until workers complete and join main process
    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()

    print('Program completed.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This seems to work fine. I will update this if I discover anything new. Thank you all.

Comment: Excellent solution.  I forgot about task_queue.task_done, which solves the race condition I couldn't resolve: how can I know when both the queue is empty and no tasks are running.